# Audio Signal Processing in iOS

Tags: ios, signal-processing, audio

I'm about to start developing an iOS application for audio processing. At this moment it is not quite sure what the requirements for the application are since this is a research project. But  basic requirements are at least to detect cords, on-sets from mic input. Therefore I value your opinion on available libraries which you think are good for this kind of work. I would like to stay away from third party libraries as much as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use audio units.
No third party stuff, just plain audio units which is the best audio interface on iOS anyway.
Slightly tricky to start with, but read the docs and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Could you provide links to said docs?

Comment: Thanks for you answers. There are some existing code writing(C++) using JUCE library. Theoretically they should be able to mix with Audio Units since they are written in C++. What do you think about this? Did you have similar experiences where you faced some problems.

Comment: By the way , have you done on-set detections using Audio Units

Comment: I don't know JUCE, and I'm not even sure what's on-set detection but I've done lots of audio processing in C++ using audio units. Here are the apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitHostingGuide_iOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009492

Comment: on-set is the beginning of a musical note. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I'd recommend using the Novocaine library. Audio stuff is a real pain if you do it yourself from scratch...

https://github.com/alexbw/novocaine

### Here's what they say:

Really fast audio in iOS and Mac OS X using Audio Units is hard, and will leave you scarred and bloody. What used to take days can now be done with just a few lines of code.

### Getting Audio

```
Novocaine *audioManager = [Novocaine audioManager];
[audioManager setInputBlock:^(float *newAudio, UInt32 numSamples, UInt32 numChannels) {
    // Now you're getting audio from the microphone every 20 milliseconds or so. How's that for easy?
    // Audio comes in interleaved, so,
    // if numChannels = 2, newAudio[0] is channel 1, newAudio[1] is channel 2, newAudio[2] is channel 1, etc.
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But can I do any audio processing using this library?

Answer (score 3):

Audio Graph (https://github.com/tkzic/audiograph) demonstrates how to read audio from the microphone, audio files, and MIDI files. It also processes them in both time domain and frequency domain (for chord detection, you might need some analysis in the frequency domain). Being a modification of Apple's MixerHost example, it does not use any third party libraries.

Aurio Touch (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/aurioTouch2/Introduction/Intro.html) by Apple is a bit harder to learn, but contains what you need to start with. And this does not involve any third party libraries.

Comment: Just update the Aurio Touch's URL:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/aurioTouch2/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011369-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Comment: Updated above, with thanks.

Comment: A newer version of Aurio Touch has been made to support iOS 7: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/aurioTouch/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 1):

Core Audio and the Accelerate framework are built into iOS.  No need for any 3rd party libraries.  Lots if documentation on Apple's Developer web site.  For real-time low latency audio input, try the RemoteIO Audio Unit, also built into iOS Core Audio.

There is also a book on Learning Core Audio.

The Accelerate framework contains a lot of basic DSP building blocks, such as FFTs, matrix math and biquad filters.